# Mule no object DCH for MIME type application/pdf

Tags: mule, attachment, mime

I am trying to Set an Attachment as below:

```
<set-attachment attachmentName="abc" value="#[contents]" contentType="#[fileType]" doc:name="Attachment"/>
```

The contentType happens to be application/pdf. I get the following error for .pdf and .doc files. text/plain files go through ok.

1. no object DCH for MIME type application/pdf (javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException)
   javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler:891 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/activation/UnsupportedDataTypeException.html)
2. Could not write attachments. (org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault)
   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor$AttachmentOutEndingInterceptor:105 (null)

Any idea how to allow for application/pdf and/or .doc files for that matter? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You present an incomplete flow. It's hard to tell what you are doing with the message and its attachment.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with some of the dependencies, I have just tried with 3.5.2 and it works fine for application/pdf.
Please try downloading the lastest and greatest version.