# Sending pdf attachments in Mule errors "no object DCH for MIME type"

Tags: mule, jakarta-mail

Versions: Mule 3.6, JRE 7, javax.mail 1.5.4

Problem:  Sending SMTP Email with PDF attachment fails with error:

`javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type application/pdf`

Code to send email:

```
        DataSource fileDataSource =new FileDataSource("c:\\temp\\agreement.pdf");
        InputStream fi = fileDataSource.getInputStream();
        DataSource fileDataSource1 = new ByteArrayDataSource(fi, "application/pdf");
        msg.addOutboundAttachment("agreement.pdf", fileDataSource1, "application/pdf");
```

Switching to sending a text/plain, or text/html works fine.

After reading [SO-Mule no object DCH for MIME type application/pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835693/mule-no-object-dch-for-mime-type-application-pdf) I have tried upgrading to javax.mail.jar 1.5.4 but problem persists.

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521027/dch-class-error-with-javamail)?

Comment: @jmehrens thanks - I tried those, but no luck.  I've switched to AWS' SES with their Java API  libs - works like a charm.

Comment: Good to hear.  I was thinking that the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#securityManager) for debugging activation could help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a few days ago but with text/calendar and plain java. I edited my solution to your content-type. Just add the following code to the beggining of your method:

```
final MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypes = (MimetypesFileTypeMap) MimetypesFileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap();
mimetypes.addMimeTypes("application/pdf pdf PDF");
final MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap) MailcapCommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
mailcap.addMailcap("application/pdf;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
```

I hope this fits for your case too.